# When using Implicit Flow with a SPA, where do we actually create the account in our Database?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application, openid-connect, implicit-flow

I'm trying to understand how OAuth2.0 Implicit Flow (with OIDC) works with a pretty simple SPA/Mobile client (aka Client) and my REST Api (aka Resource Server) **and creating new accounts**.

I more or less understand how the Client can request a token from an Auth Service (Auth0/Stormpath/IdentityServer/etc). It then uses this token to access restricted API endpoints.

But all the examples I keep reading are that the 'accounts' are created on these Auth Services (which is required and I understand) but nothing is created on *my* service (my Resource Server).

I need to create an account in my DB because I have user data/settings I wish to store (eg. orders they make, etc). Of course, I *do NOT* want to store any security information .. because that's why I'm using an external Auth Service.

So, would anyone explain how they use implicit flow and .. when a token (or more specifically, when OpenID Connect is used to get the user information) is returned, you figure out if a user exists or not and creates one if it's new.

I also grok that the token `issuer_id + sub` are both required to determine a `unique` user from the point of an Auth Service.

Lastly, how do you prevent 'new account spam/abuse' ? I'm assuming that at some point in your Client (which checks for a local-storage token before each Rest API request because we need to stick some token in the `bearer` header) ...that when you decide to create a new user ... my REST Api (aka the Resource Server) will have an endpoint to create new users .. like `POST /account/` .. so how do protect your server from getting spam'd new random POST's that create new accounts? IP+time-delay restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where do we actually create the account in our Database?

Create a database table that includes an `iss` and `sub` column. Setup those columns as a unique compound key that represents a user. Insert user accounts in there.

> So, can anyone explain how they use implicit flow and .. when a token (or more specifically, when OpenID Connect is used to get the user information) is returned, you figure out if a user exists or not and creates one if it's new?

It sounds like you already know the answer.

1. Parse the `id_token`.
2. Retrieve the `iss` and `sub`.
3. Check your app's table for that `iss` + `sub` key.
4. If it's there, then that user exists. If it isn't, then create the user.

From the spec:

> Subject Identifier: Locally unique and never reassigned identifier within the Issuer for the End-User, which is intended to be consumed by the Client.

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html

The `iss` and `sub` act as a unique compound key that represents the user. Here is an example `id_token`.

```
{
 alg: "RS256",
 kid: "1e9gdk7"
}.
{
 iss: "http://server.example.com",
 sub: "248289761001",
 aud: "s6BhdRkqt3",
 nonce: "n-0S6_WzA2Mj",
 exp: 1311281970,
 iat: 1311280970
}.
[signature]
```

Treat the `iss` + `sub` compound key in the same way that you would treat any other unique user identifier.

> so how do protect your server from getting spam'd new random POST's that create new accounts?

Setup Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) restrictions, so that only your SPA's domain is allowed to POST to the `/api/account` endpoint.

Comment: Ok great! So when I get the token I need to then hit our API to check if a user is required to be made or just use the existing one. Also, I can use CORS restrictions (white listing?) to protect that endpoint.